# Why absolutely positioned elements render over previous absolutely positioned element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

In this code,

```css
#parent-div{
 background: #B3bEb5;
 border: 0.1em solid black;
}


#default{
  background: #DBE9F4;
}
#centered{
  background: #89CFF0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* text-align: left, right, center, justify */
#centered-text{
  text-align: center;
}

/* Absolute Positioning : Positioning Based on the Document */
#top-left-pos{
  background: #89CFF0;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  
}

#bottom-right-tl-parent {
  background: #DBE9F4;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#another-pos{
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
      <div id="default">Default</div>
      <div id="centered">Centered</div>
      <div id="centered-text">Centered Text</div>
    </div>

    
    <!-- Demonstrate Absolute Postioning -->

    <div id="top-left-pos">Top Left
      <div id="bottom-right-tl-parent">Bottom Right Parent</div>
    </div>

    <div id="another-pos">Top Right
    </div>
```

absolutely positioned `top-left-pos` element, positions in next row to `centered-text` element, whose behaviour similar to static positioned elements.

But, 
below is the output,

### [image]

So, Why every new absolutely positioned element `another-pos`is rendered over previous absolutely positioned element `top-left-pos`? why `another-pos` element is not rendered as next block element?

With the above code, am expecting `another-pos` element to be rendered as shown below,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, Why every new absolutely positioned element another-posis rendered
>   over previous absolutely positioned element top-left-pos? why
>   another-pos element is not rendered as next block element?

"The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor(non static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used."

Src: [CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

This means that if you have 1 or 10 elements using `position: absolute`, they all start at the same top/left position (if you omit those values in your css rule).

As such they are also taken out of normal flow, which below sample shows, where yet another div, `#another-nonpos`, using normal flow starts after the previous normal flowed element.

It also shows that positioned elements have a higher z-index than non positioned, making them stay in a higher layer (on top of).

Further reading about z-index: [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)

```css
#parent-div{
 background: #B3bEb5;
 border: 0.1em solid black;
}
#default{
  background: #DBE9F4;
}
#centered{
  background: #89CFF0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

/* text-align: left, right, center, justify */
#centered-text{
  text-align: center;
}

/* Absolute Positioning : Positioning Based on the Document */
#top-left-pos{
  background: #89CFF0;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  
}

#bottom-right-tl-parent {
  background: #DBE9F4;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

#another-pos{
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 110px;
}
#another-nonpos{
  background: lime;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div">
  <div id="default">Default</div>
  <div id="centered">Centered</div>
  <div id="centered-text">Centered Text</div>
</div>


<!-- Demonstrate Absolute Postioning -->

<div id="top-left-pos">Top Left
  <div id="bottom-right-tl-parent">Bottom Right Parent</div>
</div>

<div id="another-pos">Top Right
</div>

<div id="another-nonpos">Non absolute
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `#top-left-pos` has greater value of `z-index` property

Comment: OK let me rephrase like this, if I remove `z-index` property, then why every new absolutely positioned  element is sitting on previous absolutely positioned element? why new element is not rendered as next block element?

Comment: In that case all DIVs have the same `z-index` value. Hence every new DIV is placed on top of the previous one. You should set the `z-index` according to the level of the DIVs. As greater the value of `z-index` as higher the level of the DIV.

Comment: If every new DIV has greater `z-index` than previous DIV, then, also new DIV sits on top of previous DIV

Comment: That's correct if they have the same parent. `z-index` cannot be more than `z-index` of the parent element.

Comment: for you case it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Because both the elements have same z index and you have not specified the left and top parameters.If both of them have same z-index and also no coordinates are specified  the second one would be placed over the previous one .

```
#top-left-pos {
        top: 0;
    }
```

Set top property to a number will solve the issue

https://jsfiddle.net/00s3f6gj/

Answer (score 0):

When using `position:absolute` , the div has nothing to do with the document and and gets the parent level regardless of using `z-index`. in your case, the `bottom-right-tl-parent` is the child of `top-left-pos`, thus increasing `z-index` value wont effect its level. if you move the `bottom-right-tl-parent` out of top-left-pos, you will be able to apply your `z-index` and it will work:

```
<div id="top-left-pos">Top Left</div>
<div id="bottom-right-tl-parent">Bottom Right Parent</div>
```

Comment: my question is, By removing `z-index` proeprty,  why `another-pos` is sitting over  `top-left-pos` element?

Comment: @overexchange what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @overexchange by removing the z-index of another-pos you have two divs with absolute positioning and one div(parent-div) with auto positioning.All three have same z-index.

Answer (score 0):

The *z-index* is initially set to auto and applies on all positioned elements. So as the element with id "top-left-pos" has a specified *z-index* its value is always higher than auto. So, it always stays on top.

Comment: What if all the positioned elements have `z-index` value `auto`?

Comment: @AbleJohnson Why absolutely positioned element `parent-div` does not get the width of a viewport? [here](https://jsfiddle.net/00s3f6gj/2/)

Comment: @Overexchange because absolute positioned element take dimension from its children also specifying width % is not valid in absolute positioning

Comment: Is it true for all types of positioned elements except static?